# Getting "a generic error occurred in gdi+" only on live server, every thing is working on localhost

Tags: asp.net, image-processing, gdi+

I am using the following code to resize and save an image.  Please get me out of this error.  I'm geting this error only on my live server, while it's working on localhost.

```
public void ResizeImage(Int32 height, Int32 width, Stream fromStream, String filename)
{
    var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fromStream);
    var newWidth = width;
    var newHeight = height;

    var thumbnailBitmap = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
    var thumbnailGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailBitmap);
    thumbnailGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

    thumbnailGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

    thumbnailGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle);
    //thumbnailBitmap.Save(toStream, image.RawFormat);
    String path = Server.MapPath("~/signatures/" + filename);
    thumbnailBitmap.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    thumbnailGraph.Dispose();

    thumbnailBitmap.Dispose();
    image.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Google?  Seems like it could be caused by a few things.  Since it only crashes on the server, my first guess would be that ASP.NET doesn't have write permission in the folder you're saving to.  See here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2009/02/28/solving-quot-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-quot-exception.aspx

Comment: thanx dear, i think u r ryt, when i simply saved the image, m getting error "File path access denied".... i think its older permission issue..

Comment: @ADSinghKamboj, it figures.  Just have to grant your ASP.NET process write access to that path.

Comment: is dis possible with code behind to grant write permission?? or i hv to change folder's permission on IIS?

Comment: Have to change the folder's permissions in Windows where IIS is hosted.