# A generic error occurred in GDI+ when I try to replace images from a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting an error (A generic error occurred in GDI+.) when I try to replace images from a folder .It works fine when it runs in localhost.

Here is my Code :

```
    if (FuBannerImg2.HasFile)
    {
        int width = 1920;
        int height = 1280;
        Stream stream = FuBannerImg2.PostedFile.InputStream;

        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(stream);

        Bitmap target = new Bitmap(width, height);
        Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(target);
        graphic.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
        target.Save(Server.MapPath("~/img/bg-img/bgimg1.jpg"));
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "clientScript", "alert('Image uploaded Successfully')", true);
        fillhome();
```

;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JstAc.png)

Comment: Please share some details about the error that you encountered and clarify which line throwed it.

Comment: Consider updating the code with something a bit more "complete" than just a fragment -  consider a private method for the code in the condition to make it more S in SOLID to make Uncle Bob followers more satisfied.

Comment: Did you get a stack trace?  If so what does that tell you?
Similar https://stackoverflow.com/q/10425430/125981  and https://stackoverflow.com/q/54715109/125981   Note this is likely not a great choice for use on "not localhost" which probably means a server/service here? When it is more a desktop thing. i.e. big pink caution here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0

Comment: It throwed in this line Line 181:            target.Save(Server.MapPath("~/img/bg-img/bgimg.jpg"));

Comment: For stack trace i have added a screen shot of the error in the above post ..do check it